# QBXML, Web Connector and how to queue another request

Tags: c#, qbxml

I'm using ASP.NET WebService to interact with QB Web Connector. I want to use iterators, but I don't know how to queue another request after getting first response. I found this method in PHP solution:

QuickBooks_Queue::enqueue()

http://www.consolibyte.com/wiki/doku.php/quickbooks_integration_php_consolibyte_webconnector

But I cannot find C# equivalent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. sendRequestXML function will be called as long as receiveResponseXML function return value is less than 100.